# Project Structure iText7

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I want to get IText7 to convert HTML to PDF with css, but can't get the BaseURI setup correctly.
Some of the css is external file, some is through CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/assessment.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
```

My structure from the src directory is:

```
|   +---resources
|   |   \---main
|   |       |   application.properties
|   |       |   
|   |       +---static  
|   |       |   +---css
|   |       |   |       assessment.css
|   |       |   |       
|   |       |   \---js
|   |       |           assessment.js
|   |       |           
|   |       \---templates
|   |               assessment.html
|   |               finished.html
|   |               greeting.html
|   |               output.html
```

so I tried :

```
public static final String BASEURI = "src/resources/main/static"
```

but I get pages of stack errors:

```
2018-09-04 12:02:17.881 ERROR 11008 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.i.s.r.resource.ResourceResolver        : Unable to retrieve stream with given base URI (file:/C:/Users/AlGrant/IdeaProjects/needsassessment/) and source path (../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2)
```

and

```
2018-09-04 12:02:17.887 ERROR 11008 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.i.h.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor   : Unable to retrieve font:
 @font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg')
```

and

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\AlGrant\IdeaProjects\assessment\css\assessment.css (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

and

```
2018-09-04 13:34:16.922 ERROR 16808 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.i.s.css.parse.CssRuleSetParser         : Error while parsing css selector: .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid~.custom-control-label::before

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported pseudo css selector: :valid
```

My java class looks like:

```
    public static final String BASEURI = "src/main/resources/static";
@Qualifier("templateEngine")
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
public void createPdf(String templateName, Map map) throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(templateName, "The templateName can not be null");
    Context ctx = new Context();
    if (map != null) {
        Iterator itMap = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itMap.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) itMap.next();
            ctx.setVariable(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue());
        }
    }

    String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);

    try {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\tmp\\assessment.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(processedHtml, pdfDoc, converterProperties);
        System.out.println("PDF created successfully");
    }
```

Do all resources need to be local? The iText docs say the BaseURI maybe an external file or online file (CDN?) but doesnt show how to include CDNs and local CSS?

Comment: Al Grant, did my answer help or do you still have an open question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a String constant `BASEURI` but I don't see you using it anywhere.

According to the iText 7 pdfHTML examples (e.g. [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf)), you need to set that URI as a value of your `ConverterProperties` in your method `createPdf`:

```java
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setBaseUri(BASEURI);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(processedHtml, pdfDoc, converterProperties);
```